# Confusing text from the official docs

Tags: android, service

I have some confusion with the following text about Service Usage (coming from the official document)

"*If a component calls `bindService()` to create the service and `onStartCommand()` is not called, the service runs only as long as the component is bound to it. After the service is unbound from all of its clients, the system destroys it.*"
Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Does the text mean that we don't have to call `startService()` (to create a service) before calling `bindService()`?

Please explain it to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answer of your question that mentioned in official document:

Although this documentation generally discusses started and bound services separately, your service can work both ways—it can be started (to run indefinitely) and also allow binding. It's simply a matter of whether you implement a couple of callback methods: onStartCommand() to allow components to start it and onBind() to allow binding.

That is mean when you start a service in binding mode the service runs until related component exists but when you start a service by calling startService it runs indefinitely.

Comment: how do you " start a service in binding mode"? what method to be called?

Comment: There are two methods: startService() and bindService(). You should look at below link to find more details.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)